# slot-filling intent-detection joint model

Tags: nlp, recurrent-neural-network, gated-recurrent-unit

Hi everybody i have developed two RNN models for a chatbot.Let's say that user says:"Tell me how the weather will be tomorrow in Paris".
The first model will be able to recognize the user's intent WEATHER_INFO , while the second one will be able to extract meaningful information from the phrase like LOC:Paris and DATE:tomorrow
Of course there are many other intent categories like for example MUSIC_PLAY and so on.
Since the two model are not linked in any way for the same phrase we could have for example the results
intent:WEATHER_INFO and TITLE:Paris , where the slot TITLE is instead linked to the MUSIC_PLAY intention
Many researchers tried to improve performance creating a joint model where the two models use the other one in order to avoid this kind of error
here my code for the slot filling nn

```
from keras.models import Model, Input
from keras.layers import LSTM, Embedding, Dense, TimeDistributed, Dropout, Bidirectional
import keras as k
from keras_contrib.layers import CRF


# input = Input(shape=(140,))
# input = Input(shape=(len(X_train),max_len))
input = Input(shape=(max_len,))

# word_embedding_size = 150
word_embedding_size = 150
n_words = len(token_ids)


# Embedding Layer
model = Embedding(input_dim=n_words, output_dim=word_embedding_size, input_length=max_len)(input)
# model = Embedding(input_dim=n_words, output_dim=word_embedding_size, input_length=140)(input)

# BI-LSTM Layer
model = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=word_embedding_size,
                           return_sequences=True,
                           dropout=0.5,
                           recurrent_dropout=0.5,
                           kernel_initializer=k.initializers.he_normal()))(model)
model = LSTM(units=word_embedding_size * 2,
             return_sequences=True,
             dropout=0.5,
             recurrent_dropout=0.5,
             kernel_initializer=k.initializers.he_normal())(model)

# TimeDistributed Layer
model = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_tags, activation="relu"))(model)

# CRF Layer
crf = CRF(n_tags)

out = crf(model)  # output
model = Model(input, out)

# In[]

# model compile and fit

from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Optimiser
adam = k.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0005, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)

# Compile model
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss=crf.loss_function, metrics=[crf.accuracy, 'accuracy'])

model.summary()

# Saving the best model only
filepath = "ner-bi-lstm-td-model-{val_accuracy:.2f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

# Fit the best model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=256, epochs=10, validation_split=0.1, verbose=1,
                    callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

and here the code for the intent detection NN

```
#CNN architecture    

from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K
from keras import layers

batch_size = 128

epochs = 12
if nn_architecture == 'CNN':
    model_CNN = Sequential()
    e = Embedding(vocab_size, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=max_length, trainable=False)
    model_CNN.add(e)
    model_CNN.add(Dropout(0.2))
    # we add a Convolution1D, which will learn filters
    # word group filters of size filter_length:
    filters = 50
    kernel_size = 3    
    hidden_dims = 250
    model_CNN.add(layers.Conv1D(filters,
                     kernel_size,
                     padding='valid',
                     activation='relu',
                     strides=1))
    # we use max pooling:
    model_CNN.add(layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D())

    # We add a vanilla hidden layer:
    model_CNN.add(Dense(hidden_dims))
    model_CNN.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model_CNN.add(layers.Activation('relu'))

    # We project onto a single unit output layer, and squash it with a sigmoid:
    model_CNN.add(Dense(nbClasses)) # no_of_categories
    model_CNN.add(layers.Activation('sigmoid'))

    model_CNN.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    history_CNN =model_CNN.fit(X_train, Y_train_c,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              epochs=epochs,
              #validation_split=0.2
              )
    # Epoch 12/12
    # 38771/38771 [==============================] - 11s 276us/step - 
    #loss: 0.0046 - accuracy: 0.9985
```

What I would like to is to merge this two architectures in order to obtain this
[image]

Please help me ... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's hardly a research problem nowadays, but nevertheless...
Here is article on github.io that does exactly what you'd want - combines intent classification and slot filling tasks in one model.
https://chsasank.github.io/spoken-language-understanding.html

Since links only answers are frowned upon, here is model architecture as well - I modified it slightly, but in general here is Keras code:

```
def build_model(self):
    main_input = Input(shape=(15), dtype='int32', name='main_input')
    x = Embedding(output_dim=self.embedding_dimension, input_dim=n_vocab, input_length=15)(main_input)
    x = Convolution1D(64, 5, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)

    if self.dropout_parameter > 0.0:
        x = Dropout(self.dropout_parameter)(x)

    if self.rnn_type is 'GRU':
        rnn = GR    def build_model(self):
    main_input = Input(shape=(15), dtype='int32', name='main_input')
    x = Embedding(output_dim=self.embedding_dimension, input_dim=n_vocab, input_length=15)(main_input)
    x = Convolution1D(64, 5, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)

    if self.dropout_parameter > 0.0:
        x = Dropout(self.dropout_parameter)(x)

    if self.rnn_type is 'GRU':
        rnn = GRU(self.rnn_units, return_sequences=True)

    elif self.rnn_type is 'LSTM':
        rnn = LSTM(self.rnn_units, return_sequences=True)
    else:
        rnn = SimpleRNN(self.rnn_units)

    if self.bidirectional:
        rnn_slot = Bidirectional(rnn)(x)
    else:
        rnn_slot = rnn(x)

    rnn_intent = GRU(self.rnn_units, return_sequences=False)(x)

    if self.maxPooling:
        x = MaxPooling1D(strides=1, padding='same')(x)
        print("Using MaxPooling")
    elif self.averagePooling:
        x = AveragePooling1D(strides=1, padding='same')(x)
        print("Using AveragePooling")
    slot_output = Dense(n_slots, activation='softmax', name='slot_output')(rnn_slot)
    intent_output = Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax', name='intent_output')(rnn_intent)
    model = kerasModel(inputs=[main_input], outputs=[intent_output, slot_output])

    # rmsprop is recommended for RNNs https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315743/rmsprop-and-adam-vs-sgd
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss={'intent_output': 'categorical_crossentropy', 'slot_output': 'categorical_crossentropy'}, metrics='accuracy')
    model.summary()
    self.model = model

    return 0U(self.rnn_units, return_sequences=True)

    elif self.rnn_type is 'LSTM':
        rnn = LSTM(self.rnn_units, return_sequences=True)
    else:
        rnn = SimpleRNN(self.rnn_units)

    if self.bidirectional:
        rnn_slot = Bidirectional(rnn)(x)
    else:
        rnn_slot = rnn(x)

    rnn_intent = GRU(self.rnn_units, return_sequences=False)(x)

    if self.maxPooling:
        x = MaxPooling1D(strides=1, padding='same')(x)
        print("Using MaxPooling")
    elif self.averagePooling:
        x = AveragePooling1D(strides=1, padding='same')(x)
        print("Using AveragePooling")
    slot_output = Dense(n_slots, activation='softmax', name='slot_output')(rnn_slot)
    intent_output = Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax', name='intent_output')(rnn_intent)
    model = kerasModel(inputs=[main_input], outputs=[intent_output, slot_output])

    # rmsprop is recommended for RNNs https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315743/rmsprop-and-adam-vs-sgd
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss={'intent_output': 'categorical_crossentropy', 'slot_output': 'categorical_crossentropy'}, metrics='accuracy')
    model.summary()
    self.model = model

    return 0
```